# "Connection to a local service are denied since..." error with Torsocks - how do I connect to a local MysQL Server anyway?

Tags: mysql, networking, tor, torsocks

So I have a python script that is supposed to run anonymized. I use Torsocks for that. But a part of the script needs to write data into a MySQL database running on the same device. But torsocks is denying the connection since it could be leaking my ID. The error I receive is:

```
1560504024 WARNING torsocks[20011]: [connect] Connection to a local address are denied since it might be a TCP DNS query to a local DNS server. Rejecting it for safety reasons. (in tsocks_connect() at connect.c:192)
```

followed by the Python MySQL Exception with this line summarizing it:

```
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1:3306' (1 Operation not permitted)
```

I have already tried editing the torsocks.conf, trying out different things as I had no idea what I was doing. The lines I added to the config are the following (of course only one at a time):

```
local = 127.0.0.0/127.0.0.1
local 127.0.0.0/127.0.0.1
local = 127.0.0.0/192.168.178.1
local 127.0.0.0/192.168.178.1
local = 127.0.0.0/192.168.178.0
local 127.0.0.0/192.168.178.0
local 127.0.0.0/255.255.255.255
```

But none of these worked. I always got the following warning, but tsocks started running the script anyway, it just stopped when it had to access the MySQL server.

```
1560504796 WARNING torsocks[20028]: Config file contains unknown value: *THE LINE I USED HERE* (in parse_config_line() at config-file.c:183)
```

I have absolutely no idea what to try next as I am quite a newbie and I would be really thankful for any help.

Comment: If possible, don't run the entire application through torsocks, but modify the parts that need to be anonymized to use Tor's SOCKS proxy port. Then the things that need to access the local network can, and the remote connections will use Tor.

Comment: @drew010 but how would I do this? Should I be using two different python scripts that both have to be run seperately and they exchange the data through a file?I have also seen PySocks proxy for proxifying stuff in Python, but I have no idea if this will work because I am using modules that I have not written myself that do the networking and I am not sure how exactly they work.

Comment: We would need to see your actual code snippet to answer this. Even "run anonymized" is too vague and could mean different things to different people. Are u collecting data from the Tor network and then need to write it to a database or you need your actual script to interact as a Hidden Service itself? If it is the former, I would use `requests` with `pysocks`. If it is the latter, you should use `stem`, great example here: https://jordan-wright.com/blog/2014/10/06/creating-tor-hidden-services-with-python/. Once you add more information in your question, I will try to answer.